# Running angular unit tests on jenkins taking longer time as compared to running on local

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jenkins, karma-jasmine

When running unit tests on my build my local machine takes approx 56 secs, but running the tests on our Jenkins build machine takes approx 4 mins 15.04 secs.

I tried setting barrier=0 on the disk, but it only improved performance by 10%-20%.

On local machine:
`HeadlessChrome 73.0.3683 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 528 of 548 (skipped 20) SUCCESS (56.274 secs / 54.748 secs)`
On jenkins:
`HeadlessChrome 63.0.3239 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 528 of 548 (skipped 20) SUCCESS (4 mins 15.04 secs / 4 mins 9.251 secs)`

Jenkins machine configuration: 
`A4
Basic
General purpose
8 cpu
14 GB ram
16 data disks
16x300 iops`

Comment: Are you running them with `singleRun: true` ?

Comment: Yes. I'm running them with singleRun:true.

Comment: Is Jenkins on the same computer with the same amount of resources?

Comment: Jenkins machine has higher configuration